# Floyd's Triangle

Tags: python, numbers, geometry, iteration

I have this code:

```
def floyd(n):
    count = 1
    string = ""
    for i in range(1,n+2):
        for j in range(1,i):
            string = string + " " + str(count)
            count = count + 1
        print(string)
        string = ""
print floyd(6)
```

It prints:

```
1
2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
       1
      2 3
     4 5 6
   7 8 9 10
 11 12 13 14 15
16 17 18 19 20 21
```

Will you help me figure out how to do so?

Comment: The row starting with 7 looks off-center to me. It is two spaces away from the left edge of the next row, and four spaces away from the right edge. Shouldn't the 7 be aligned so it lies over the "1" in "12"?

Answer (score 5):

Python strings actually have a built-in `center()` method that can do that for you.

```
print(string.center(total_width))
```

You can set up `total_width` in advance with:

```
total_width = -1

for i in xrange(0, n):
    total_width += 1 + len(str((n + n * n) / 2 - i))
```

Or

```
total_width = sum(1 + len(str((n + n * n) / 2 - i)) for i in xrange(0, n)) - 1
```

That is, the sum of the lengths of the string representations of the numbers in the same row as the nth triangle number (n² + n) ÷ 2.

[Here’s a demo!](http://codepad.org/ygi7uHyS)

Answer (score 2):

Using `n` you can find the last row first, the last number is `(n**2 + n)/2`, so the first number on last line is `((n**2 + n)/2) - (n-1)`, now last row is can be created using `str.join` and a list comprehension:

```
x = ((n**2 + n)/2)
last_row = ' '.join(str(s) for s in xrange(x-(n-1), x+1))
```

Now we can use the width of this line in string formatting to center other lines properly.

**Code:**

```
from itertools import count
def floyd(n):
    x = ((n**2 + n)/2)
    last_row = ' '.join(str(s) for s in xrange(x-(n-1), x+1))
    width = len(last_row)
    c = count(1)
    for x in xrange(1, n):
        line = ' '.join(str(next(c)) for _ in xrange(x))
        print "{:^{}}".format(line, width)
    print last_row
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> floyd(6)
        1        
       2 3       
      4 5 6      
    7 8 9 10     
 11 12 13 14 15  
16 17 18 19 20 21
>>> floyd(8)
           1           
          2 3          
         4 5 6         
       7 8 9 10        
    11 12 13 14 15     
   16 17 18 19 20 21   
 22 23 24 25 26 27 28  
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def FloydT(n):
    num=0
    row=""
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(1,i+1):
            num+=1
            row+=str(num)+" "
        print(str.center(row,3*n)) # this line will do what you want
        row=""
```